# Finding for constant in a standard deviation problem

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation

> Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be sample observations. Show that for any constant $c$, 
>   $$
> (n-1)s^2\le\sum(X_i-c)^2
> $$
>   where $s$ is the standard deviation of the observations.

My professor gave this to my class as a "do on your own time" sort of challenge question. On first thought it would make sense to expand the $(X_i-c)^2$ and work out the problem algebraically, but I don't think that is possible because of the summation. How does one approach a problem like this?

Comment: Please read the `[self-study]` tag's [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Can you turn the LHS into a similar-looking expression w/ a summation?

Comment: @Gung's suggestion will work well. Another approach is to find the values of $c$ that minimize the right hand side.

Comment: Speaking just for my idiosyncratic self, I'd use gung's approach and then look at re-writing the RHS to match the LHS plus an extra term that's positive. whuber's approach also works well. Which way you go depends on what you're comfortable with.

Comment: Use the identity $a^2-b^2$ = ...

Answer (score 1):

To close this one:
By the expression in the question, we can infer that

$$s^2 = \frac 1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2$$

So we want to examine whether it is valid that
$$(n-1)\frac 1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - c)^2$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - c)^2 \leq 0$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n\Big[(X_i - \bar X)^2 - (X_i - c)^2 \Big]\leq 0$$

Using the algebraic identity $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ we get

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n\Big[(X_i - \bar X+X_i - c)(X_i - \bar X - X_i + c) \Big]\leq 0$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n\Big[(2X_i - \bar X- c)(c - \bar X )\Big]\leq 0$$

The second term of the product does not depend on the index so it is taken out,

$$\Rightarrow (c - \bar X )\sum_{i=1}^n(2X_i - \bar X- c)\leq 0$$

$$\Rightarrow (c - \bar X )(2n\bar X - n\bar X - nc)\leq 0$$

$$\Rightarrow n(c - \bar X )(\bar X - c)\leq 0$$

$$\Rightarrow -n(c - \bar X )^2\leq 0$$

which holds for all values.